# How do I play this mordent?

Tags: piano

What's the second note I play? It's in the key of C major

[image]

Comment: How to realize ornaments depends somewhat on the style, so it's better to give a fuller excerpt and the name of the work. This looks like the first Invention of J. S. Bach. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music)#In_Baroque_music for some ideas, but you have freedom.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're in the key of C your second note will be G.

The auxiliary note is the next note in the key: a mordent goes to G, a reverse mordent to E natural.  If the composer wants a note outside the key you'll see an accidental above the mordent symbol.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the second note I play? It's in the key of C major

You have to play G.

From Wikipedia,

*The mordent is thought of as a rapid single alternation between an indicated note, the note above (the upper mordent) or below (the lower mordent) and the indicated note again.
The upper mordent is indicated by a short squiggle; the lower mordent is the same with a short vertical line through it:*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordent